# Spring additional configuration metadata not taking effect

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I have a project that has a configuration property, but it doesn't require the use of @Configuration and @ConfigurationProperties annotations.

So, I created an `additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json` file, which is located under `META-INF/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json`.

I added these two Maven dependencies: `spring-boot-configuration-processor`,`spring-boot-autoconfigure`

How do I resolve this issue?

In other words, if I want to make this additional configuration take effect, is it necessary to have  configurationProperties class or autoConfiguration class?